# Modifying Windows ctrl-alt-del behavior through Gina

Tags: c++, windows, gina

Hello I am trying to change the behavior of the windows xp ctrl alt del key in certain scenarios throught Gina. Specifically I want to unhook the custom dialog that appears on ctrl alt del that was implemented in legacy code, and have my task manager back. Would someone point me at the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this page: http://webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=614457

It seems to describe the procedure for restoring the default behavior for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>.